# C++ Print diagonal in two dimensional array using one point as reference

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, chess

I have a two dimensional array which represents a chess board - `t[8][8]`
Now let's say we have a queen on that game at `t[4][7]`

How to draw the diagonals using this queen reference's coordinate ?

What I have already tried:

- 2 nested for loop starting at `xQueen` position and `yQueen` position for the second loop with conditions like
  `if (i == (xQueen - i) && j == (yQueen - j))`
- Same but starting at `1` to `8`
- Using a `while` loop until the limit of the board is reached

How to locate at any point on the board if it's in the diagonal of the queen ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's number the array so that it starts from 0.

Say you have a queen at `(4, 7)`. You might find that the position you were to find include `(3, 6)`, `(2, 5)` and `(5, 6)`.

Draw them out on the paper, and you'll find it clear that what you wanted is quite simple.

If the queen is at position `(x, y)`, then all the positions `(i, j)` with `(i + j == x + y || i - j == x - y` are the answer. To make it clearer, you might want to represent each position `(i, j)` with `i + j`, and put them in the matrix. You'll find that the positions on the same diagonal have the same result. This fact is the same if you represent `(i, j)` with `i - j`.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this (not the nicest, but fast and easy to understand)

```
int startX=4;
int startY=7;

int currentX = startX;
int currentY = startY;

while (currentX >=0 && startY>=0) {
    currentX--;
    currentY--;
    chessboard[currentX][currentY] = 1;
}

int currentX = startX;
int currentY = startY;

while (currentX <=7 && startY>=0) {
    currentX++;
    currentY--;
    chessboard[currentX][currentY] = 1;
}

int currentX = startX;
int currentY = startY;

while (currentX <=7 && startY<=7) {
    currentX++;
    currentY++;
    chessboard[currentX][currentY] = 1;
}

int currentX = startX;
int currentY = startY;

while (currentX >=0 && startY<=7) {
    currentX--;
    currentY++;
    chessboard[currentX][currentY] = 1;
}
```